# Create scrollable JFrame using JScrollPane and JPanel

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jframe

As looking for a solution, i found almost the same idea in all answers in StackOverflow. But all did not work, i need to help me for a solution for that special part of code.

```
//Create a JTabbedPane for 2 tabs
mainTabs = new JTabbedPane(JTabbedPane.TOP);

//Create the first tab
reportingTabs = new JTabbedPane(JTabbedPane.TOP);

// editor is an object created from a class inherited form JPanel
editor = new GraphEditor();

//Create a JMenuBar
EditorMenuBar menuBar = new EditorMenuBar(editor);

//Create a JFrame for the editor
editorFrame = editor.createFrame();


//Create a JPanel object to contain bothe the JMenubar and the editor JFrame
JPanel editorPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());

//Here the solution, creating a JScrollPane to contain only the editor JFrame to be scrolled
JScrollPane editorScroll = new JScrollPane();

//Adding the JMenuBar and the editor JFrame to the JPanel
editorPanel.add(menuBar, BorderLayout.NORTH);
editorPanel.add(editorFrame.getContentPane());

//Involve the JPanel into the JScrollPane
editorScroll.add(editorPanel);


//Adding the tabs to the main JFrame
maingui.getContentPane().add(mainTabs);

//Adding the JScrolledPane to a tab
mainTabs.addTab("Editor", editorScroll);
```

The result, is that thers is no JFrame in maingui. (with no SCrollPane solution, it appreas correctly)

Comment: Yes i removed it, but i got NON scrollable Frame, so that i get only a part of the my graph

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove editorScroll variable completely and replace

```
     mainTabs.addTab("Editor", editorScroll);
```

with

```
     mainTabs.addTab("Editor", new JScrollPane(editorPanel));
```

It should work...

Comment: Thanks, it works, only 4 minutes to make it the correct answer